# wordpress css hover issue

Tags: html, css

**HTML**

[image]

**My CSS**

```
.bezoek_toonzaal{
background-image: url(../wp-content/uploads/2018/03/sanotech-website-home-button-contact.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: left bottom;
height: 200px;
width: 300px;
padding-top: 20px;
}

.ontdek_merken{
background-image: url(../wp-content/uploads/2018/03/sanotech-website-buttons.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: left bottom;
margin-top: 15px;
padding-top: 22px;
height: 80px;
width: 300px;
}

.toonzaal_wrap:hover .bezoek_toonzaal h4 span{
color: #005471 !important;
}

.toonzaal_wrap:hover .bezoek_toonzaal p{
color: #bdbec0 !important;
}

.toonzaal_wrap:hover .bezoek_toonzaal span{
color: #bdbec0 !important;
}

.toonzaal_wrap:hover .bezoek_toonzaal a{
color: #bdbec0 !important;
}

.toonzaal_wrap:hover .ontdek_merken span{
color: #005471 !important;
}

.bezoek_toonzaal:hover{
color: #005471 !important;
background-image: url(../wp-content/uploads/2018/03/sanotech-website-home-button-contact-wit.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: left bottom;
height: 200px;
width: 300px;
padding-top: 20px;
}

.bezoek_toonzaal h4 span:hover{
color: #005471 !important;
}

.ontdek_merken:hover{
background-image: url(../wp-content/uploads/2018/03/sanotech-website-projecten-achtergrond-grote-balk-projecten-wit.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: left bottom;
margin-top: 15px;
padding-top: 22px;
height: 80px;
width: 300px;
color: #005471 !important;
}
```

[image]

**classes:**

[image]

The text, marked in red, should stay the same color (in white = #FFF) if the other element is being hovered.
Don’t know how to do that in this scenario.
I've added the different scenario's as it currently is.
Also added the classes.

If you have any questions or want any added info, don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: how is this related to WordPress?

Comment: cause I made the website in wordpress....?

Comment: Please share the HTML code in text form as well, not just as an image. And preferably a [mcve], executable either here via code snippet functionality directly, or somewhere else to look at “live”, would also be a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it myself:

**CSS**

```
.bezoek_toonzaal:hover{
    color: #005471 !important;
    background-image: url(https://sanotech.my-tagit.be/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/sanotech-website-home-button-contact-wit.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: left bottom;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.ontdek_merken:hover{
        background-image: url(https://sanotech.my-tagit.be/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/sanotech-website-projecten-achtergrond-grote-balk-projecten-wit.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: left bottom;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding-top: 22px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 300px;
}

.toonzaal_wrap .bezoek_toonzaal:hover h4 span{
    color: #005471 !important;
}

.toonzaal_wrap .ontdek_merken:hover span{
    color: #005471 !important;
}


.toonzaal_wrap .bezoek_toonzaal :hover span{
    color: #bdbec0 !important;
}

.toonzaal_wrap .bezoek_toonzaal:hover a{
    color: #bdbec0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to create a jsfiddle and include the html too. But try the below first:

You have to add `color: #FFF` to `.bezoek_toonzaal`

```
.bezoek_toonzaal{
    background-image: url(../wp-content/uploads/2018/03/sanotech-website-home-button-contact.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: left bottom;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    color: #FFF
}
```

You have to remove the `color: #005471 !important;` from `.ontdek_merken:hover`

```
.ontdek_merken:hover{
    background-image: url(../wp-content/uploads/2018/03/sanotech-website-projecten-achtergrond-grote-balk-projecten-wit.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: left bottom;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding-top: 22px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: I've added HTML code the browser gives me. Don't know how to retrieve the HTML from wordpress unless inspecting the webpage with the browser